# How do I dry concrete floor?

Tags: flooring

I am removing my existing vinyl flooring in my basement. The flooring was laid directly on the concrete slab by the previous owner. As I was removing the flooring I noticed some wet patches on the concrete. There was some mold under the vinyl planks that were on these patches. I suspect the moisture was from a leak which has since been addressed.

How can I dry these patches out before I begin installing my new floor?

Answer (score 3):

Use fans and/or heaters.

When its dry, turn them off and wait a day or two to ensure that the problem was fixed.

Comment: The air circulation in the basement may be limited. If so, a dehumidifier would remove the moisture from the air.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to confirm that it's not a continuing issue with moisture leaching out of the concrete and that your moisture problem is truly gone.  The standard way to test for this is to take a piece of sheet plastic (about a foot square is fine), and tape it to the floor along all edges, completely sealing the edge to the concrete floor.  Then wait a day or two, and take up the plastic.  If its dry underneath, you should be good.  But if it's damp underneath where the plastic was, then you still have moisture issues.  The specific plastic is not critical, but often people use a piece of kitchen cling-wrap since it's cheap, and usually easily available in most kitchens already.